# NoReverseMatch Error trying to render from html to pdf

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am a newbie on Django and I am currently working on this result management project, I actually downloaded the whole project from a website but while trying to explore its functionalities especially while trying to render the result to show me a pdf file. I encountered an error reading

> NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/find-result/4/result/ Reverse for 'pdf' not found. 'pdf' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I actually intended to later tweak the models to conform with my own specifications to build the Result Management System but as seen I can not proceed. I need some help.

Below are the codes.

Views.py

```
# import list

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print("\nUser Name = ",username)
        print("Password = ",password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
        else:
            context = {'message':'Invalid User Name and Password'}
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name': 'Riajul Kashem', 'pass': 'login@srms'})


class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cls'] = StudentClass.objects.count()
        context['results'] = DeclareResult.objects.count()
        context['students'] = Student.objects.count()
        context['subjects'] = Subject.objects.count()
        return context
    

def find_result_view(request):
    student_class = DeclareResult.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        # data = json.loads(form)
        roll = int(data['rollid'])
        pk = int(data['class'])
        clss = get_object_or_404(DeclareResult, pk=pk)
        if clss.select_student.student_roll == roll:
            data = {
                'pk': data['class']
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            pk = '0'
            data = {
                'pk': pk
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
    return render(request, 'find_result.html', {'class':student_class})

def result(request, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(DeclareResult, pk=pk)
    lst = []
    marks = []
    for i in range(int(len(object.marks)/2)):
        lst.append(object.marks['subject_'+str(i)])
        lst.append(object.marks['subject_'+str(i)+'_mark'])
        marks.append(lst)
        lst = []
    return render(request, 'result.html', {'object':object,'pk':pk, 'marks':marks})


class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:dashboard')
    template_name = 'password_change_form.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PasswordChangeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main_page_title'] = 'Admin Change Password'
        context['panel_title'] = 'Admin Change Password'
        return context


def renderPdf(template, content={}):
    t = get_template(template)
    send_data = t.render(content)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(send_data.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type = 'application/pdf')
    else:
        response = HttpResponseServerError("Error Getting Result")

    return response


class pdf(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        try:
            query = get_object_or_404(DeclareResult, id=id)
        except:
            Http404('Content Not Found')
        marks = []
        lst = []
        for i in range(int(len(query.marks)/2)):
            lst.append(query.marks['subject_'+str(i)])
            lst.append(query.marks['subject_'+str(i)+'_mark'])
            marks.append(lst)
            lst = []
        article_pdf = renderPdf('result.html', {'object': query, 'marks':marks})
        return HttpResponse(article_pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Urls.py

```
app_name = 'dashboard'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('find-result/', views.find_result_view, name='find_result'),
    path('change-password/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='change_password'),
    path('find-result/<int:pk>/result/', views.result, name='get_result'),
]
```

Base.html

```
{% load static %}
{% include 'snipets/header_static_files.html' %}

<body class="top-navbar-fixed">
<div class="main-wrapper">
    
    {% block main_wrapper %}
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-container">
        
                <div class="left-sidebar bg-black-300 box-shadow ">
                    <div class="sidebar-content">
                        <div class="user-info closed">
                            <img src="{% static 'images/profile.jpg' %}" alt="Riajul Kashem" class="img-circle profile-img " width="100px" height="100px">
                            <h6 class="title">Riajul Kashem</h6>
                            <small class="info">Django Developer</small>
                        </div>
                        {% include 'snipets/sidebar_nav.html' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="main-page">
                    {% block main_page %}
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row page-title-div">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    {% block main_page_title %}
                                    {% endblock main_page_title %}
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="row breadcrumb-div">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                    <li><a href="{% url 'dashboard:dashboard' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                                    {% block breadcumb %}
                                    {% endblock breadcumb %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.row -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        
                    <section class="section">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
        
                            {% block main_page_content %}
                            <div class="row">
                                {% block panel %}
                                {% endblock panel %}
                            </div>
                            {% endblock main_page_content %}
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    {% endblock main_page %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% include 'snipets/nav.html' %}

    {% endblock main_wrapper %}
</div>
{% include 'snipets/footer_static_files.html' %}
{% block javascript_code %}
{% endblock javascript_code %}
</body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main_wrapper %}
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="row text-center d-block">
            <h2 class="text-primary bold pb-25"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Student Result Management System</a></h2>
        </div>
        <h4 style="text-align:right"><a href="{% url 'dashboard:pdf' id=object.id %}" target="_blank">Save as PDF</a></h4>
        <div class="container" id="marksheet">
            <p>
                <b>Student Name     : </b>  {{ object.select_student.student_name | safe }}
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Student Class    : </b>  {{ object.select_class.class_name }}   ( <b>{{ object.select_class.section | safe }}</b> )
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Student Roll : </b> {{ object.select_student.student_roll | safe }}
            </p>
            <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Mark Sheet</h2>
            
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Subject Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Mark</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-row">
                    
                    {% for mark in marks %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                            
                            {% for m in mark %}
                                <td>{{ m }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                                
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        <div class="shadow-lg p-3">
            <span class="link"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back To Home</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>   
{% endblock main_wrapper %}
```

project level urls

```
from dashboard import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('results/', include('results.urls')),
    path('subjects/', include('subjects.urls')),
    path('students/', include('students.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('classes/', include('student_classes.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please add the template `result.html` to your question.

Comment: I don't really have the result.html initially, i just added it and that is the content as edited on the post

Comment: Can I see your project level url.py file ?

Comment: @OLUYELESUNDAYANTHONY I believe one of your included templates like `snipets/header_static_files.html`, `snipets/sidebar_nav.html`, etc. should have something like `{% url 'pdf' %}` in them. That is likely where your error comes from.

Comment: @Kishore i already added it on the post. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i have `<h4 style="text-align:right"><a href="{% url 'dashboard:pdf' id=object.id %}" target="_blank">Save as PDF</a></h4>` in my new updated result.html

Comment: Hi. I think this because the url mapping is missing. Can you try to add `path('pdf', views.pdf.as_view(), name='pdf'),` inside `urlpatterns` in dashboard's `urls.py`?